# new order does not get created

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I have set an attribute  `validity_date` for each product. When I order the items. I want to separate the single order into multiple orders grouped by `validity_date`. I found some code to create an order and I used that one, but it is not creating the order. I supposed that after the function diversify gets called that there is 1 order for each items of a single day and the overall order, but there is just the overall order. Can you help me why the function createOrder is not creating orders.

```
<?php    
class AAA_OrderDiversify_Model_Observer {

    /**
     * Gets Called after the first order got created
     */
    public function diversify(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote = $event->getQuote();
        $quote_id = $quote->getId();
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());

        $orderProductArray = $this->getProductsOrderedByValidityDate($order);

        Mage::log($orderProductArray);

        foreach ($orderProductArray as $validityDate => $productCollection) {
          $this->createOrder($customer, $order, $productCollection, $validityDate);
        }


    }

    public function getProductsOrderedByValidityDate($order) {

        // get all products
        $productCollection = $order->getAllItems();

        // sort all products for each day
        $orderProductArray = array();
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $validityDate = $product->getProduct()->getData('validity_date');
            if ( !array_key_exists($validityDate, $orderProductArray) ) {
                $orderProductArray[$validityDate] = array();
            }

            array_push($orderProductArray[$validityDate], array(
              'product' => $product->getProduct()->getData('entity_id'),
              'qty' => $product->getQtyOrdered()
            ));

        }
        return $orderProductArray;
    }

    protected function createOrder($customer, $baseOrder, $products, $validityDate)
    {
        $transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
        $storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
        $reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType('order')
            ->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

        $subTotal = 0;
        $currencyCode  = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setQuoteId(0)
            ->setGlobalCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setBaseCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setStoreCurrencyCode($currencyCode)
            ->setOrderCurrencyCode($currencyCode);


        $order->setCustomerEmail($customer->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
            ->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
            ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
            ->setCustomer($customer);

        $order->setBillingAddress($baseOrder->getBillingAddress());
        $order->setShippingAddress($baseOrder->getShippingAddress());
              // -setShippingMethod();

        $order->setPayment($baseOrder->getPayment());

        foreach ($products as $requestData) {
            $request = new Varien_Object();
            $request->setData($requestData);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($request['product']);

            $cartCandidates = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
                ->prepareForCartAdvanced($request, $product);


            if (is_string($cartCandidates)) {
                throw new Exception($cartCandidates);
            }

            if (!is_array($cartCandidates)) {
                $cartCandidates = array($cartCandidates);
            }

            $parentItem = null;
            $errors = array();
            $items = array();

            foreach ($cartCandidates as $candidate) {

                $item = $this->_productToOrderItem($candidate, $candidate->getCartQty());

                $subTotal += $candidate->getFinalPrice() * $candidate->getCartQty();


                $items[] = $item;

                //
                // As parent item we should always use the item of first added product
                //
                if (!$parentItem) {
                    $parentItem = $item;
                }
                if ($parentItem && $candidate->getParentProductId()) {
                    $item->setParentItem($parentItem);
                }
                //
                // We specify qty after we know about parent (for stock)
                //
                $item->setQty($item->getQty() + $candidate->getCartQty());

                // collect errors instead of throwing first one
                if ($item->getHasError()) {
                    $message = $item->getMessage();
                    if (!in_array($message, $errors)) { // filter duplicate messages
                        $errors[] = $message;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (!empty($errors)) {
                Mage::throwException(implode("\n", $errors));
            }
            foreach ($items as $item){
                $order->addItem($item);
            }


        }

        $order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
            ->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
            ->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
            ->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

        $transaction->addObject($order);
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
        $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
        $transaction->save();

    }

    protected function _productToOrderItem(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
    {
        $rowTotal = $product->getFinalPrice() * $qty;

        $options = $product->getCustomOptions();

        $optionsByCode = array();

        foreach ($options as $option)
        {
            $quoteOption = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item_option')->setData($option->getData())
                ->setProduct($option->getProduct());

            $optionsByCode[$quoteOption->getCode()] = $quoteOption;
        }

        $product->setCustomOptions($optionsByCode);

        $options = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);

        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
            ->setStoreId($this->_storeId)
            ->setQuoteItemId(0)
            ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
            ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
            ->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
            ->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
            ->setName($product->getName())
            ->setSku($product->getSku())
            ->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setBasePrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setOriginalPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)

            ->setWeeeTaxApplied(serialize(array()))
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxRowDisposition(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setBaseWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedAmount(0)
            ->setWeeeTaxAppliedRowAmount(0)

            ->setProductOptions($options);

        return $orderItem;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, or can you tell us where the code actually breaks?

Comment: You are creating the order object but, to add the items to the order, you will need to create a quote instance and add items to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after digging around for a while. I found in the apache logs an error that says that the payment is not set. so I changed the set Payment part to:

```
    $orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setCustomerPaymentId(0)
        ->setMethod($paymentMethod) 
        ->setPoNumber(' – ');
```

Now it seems to work. no idea why "copying" an payment object doesnt work, but ok